# R: Function arguments and lapply nested in a function or called from external function with data.table

Tags: r, function, arguments, data.table, lapply

Still new to `data.table` and working with environments.

I have a `data.table` similar to this (although much larger):

```
mydt <- data.table(ID = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b"),
                   col1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
                   col2 = c(7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12),
                   key = "ID")
```

I wrote a function that takes `mydt`, splits it in a list of `data.table`s by its key, and then in each table in the list of `data.table`s takes the column, specified by the user in an argument and multiplies it by a number, provided by the user in another argument:

```
myfun <- function(data, constant, column) {
  data <- split(x = data, by = key(data))
  data <- lapply(data, function(i) {
    i[ , (column) := get(column)*constant]
  })
  return(data)
}

x <- myfun(data = mydt, constant = 3, column = "col1")

x

$a
   ID col1 col2
1:  a    3    7
2:  a    6    8
3:  a    9    9

$b
   ID col1 col2
1:  b   12   10
2:  b   15   11
3:  b   18   12
```

If I understand correctly the scoping rules in R, `lapply` will look in the environment it was called in, will find the `column` and `constant` provided as arguments to `myfun` and will use them.

However, the function passed to `lapply` is much longer and more complex than the one here and it will be used in other functions that do many other things than just splitting the `data.table`. This is why I would like to define this part as an external function that will be called within other functions. This is what I did:

```
split.dt <- function(data) {
  split(data, by = key(data))
}

mult <- function(data) {
  lapply(data, function(i) {
    i[ , (column) := get(column)*constant]
  })
}

myfun <- function(data, constant, column) {
  data <- split.dt(data = data)
  data <- mult(data = data)
}

x <- myfun(data = mydt, constant = 3, column = "col1")
```

An error is returned:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'column' not found
```

What I tried is wrapping `column` like `i[ , eval(column)]` and `i[ , eval(column)]` within the `mult` function with `parent.frame()` and `parent.env()` without any success. At the end I reached a solution where I used `sys.call` to get the arguments passed to `myfun` in a list and use them in `mult` like this:

```
split.dt <- function(data) {
  split(data, by = key(data))
}

mult <- function(data) {
  supplied.col <- sys.call(which = -1)[["column"]]
  supplied.constant <- sys.call(which = -1)[["constant"]]
  lapply(data, function(i) {
    i[ , eval(supplied.col) := get(supplied.col)*supplied.constant]
  })
}

myfun <- function(data, constant, column) {
  data <- split.dt(data = data)
  data <- mult(data = data)
}

x <- myfun(data = mydt, constant = 3, column = "col1")

x

$a
   ID col1 col2
1:  a    3    7
2:  a    6    8
3:  a    9    9

$b
   ID col1 col2
1:  b   12   10
2:  b   15   11
3:  b   18   12
```

It does work, BUT I am not sure if:

1. This is the right or most efficient approach. What is the way to make `mult` look up at the arguments supplied to `myfun`?
2. Will this work if the functions are wrapped in a package?

Comment: 1. just propagate them from `myfun` to `mult`, but I suggest you google for variable scope and have a read on the topic, then you will know how to fish :)

Comment: @John Smith: What do you mean, to include the arguments of `myfun` to `mult`, like `mult <- function(data, data, constant, column)`?

Comment: yes, exactly :)

Comment: @John Smith: Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** Just pass `column` and `constant` to `mult` as additional arguments.

```
mult <- function(data, constant, column) {
  lapply(data, function(i) {
    i[ , (column) := get(column)*constant]
  })
}

myfun <- function(data, constant, column) {
  data <- split.dt(data = data)
  data <- mult(data, constant, column)
}
```

**2)** Alternately define `mult` as:

```
mult <- function(data, envir = parent.frame()) with(envir, 
  lapply(data, function(i) {
    i[ , (column) := get(column)*constant]
  })
)
```

**2a)** or

```
mult <- function(data, envir = parent.frame()) {
  constant <- envir$constant
  column <- envir$column
  lapply(data, function(i) {
    i[ , (column) := get(column)*constant]
  })
}
```

Comment: Starting from 1.9.8 there is `split.data.table` method which do accept `by` argument, it accept character vector of column names. For details see [?split.data.table](http://jangorecki.gitlab.io/data.table/library/data.table/html/split.html).

Comment: Yes, I was on data.table 1.9.6.  Have now upgraded.

Comment: @G. Grothendieck: Thank you! What about the second question I had in my post: will the solution I figured out (using `sys.call`) work if I wrap the functions in a package (I've never done it so far)?

Comment: @G. Grothendieck: Thank you!